# can a layer 2 switch block dhcp from 1 port, both in and out?

Tags: switch, dhcp

Here's what I want to do:  "Wall" is the dhcp server from the ISP.  "R" is my internal router.  "L2" is a hypothetical switch.  "fs" is my dhcp server.  I want to connect them like this:  Wall--R--L2--fs .  I have downloaded and read some manuals for some switches that say dhcp can be prohibited on input, which, I'm guessing means the packets are just dropped.  What I hope is that a port "P" can be told to prevent dhcp in or out of that port so that I have the two dhcp servers (Wall,fs) cannot see one another.  Thus I would have this:
Wall--R--PL2--fs.  If P does not let dhcp in or out, then fs serves everything to the right of P, and Wall serves everything to the left of P.  The switch I'm mostly considering is the D-Link DGS-1210-28.  But I think that manual means it will block incoming, but not outgoing on a given port.  That won't work for me.  Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: Unless you configure "R" (router) to be a dhcp relay agent, DHCP will not cross it.

Comment: This answers my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can a layer 2 switch block dhcp?

Depending on its capabilities and configuration, a decent, managed switch *could* block DHCP, but it *won't by default*. Unmanaged switches don't block DHCP generally.

DHCP requires the server and the client to be in the same broadcast domain, ie. there must be no router in between (unless the router acts as DHCP relay and the DHCP server has a configured scope for the client subnet).

DHCP works across a switch unless

- client and server are in different VLANs and there's no relay
- DHCP snooping is used and the DHCP server isn't trusted
- there are ACLs that filter the DHCP discovery, offer, request or acknowledge

Each of the above is only possible with a managed switch and according configuration.

In your case the "fs" DHCP server is connected to your private LAN and should be able to supply addresses for clients. Any DHCP server behind the router doesn't matter for LAN clients.

Comment: This answers my question.  Thanks!